# "What should I do with...?" vs "What should I do about..?"

Tags: differences

is it any different to say, "What should I do with the cake?" or "What should I do about the cake?" Thanks for you help in advance.

Comment: They can mean the same thing, or there can be very small, nuanced differences that very much depend on context. If you need to know where to put the cake, for example, you can use both. But if there's a big problem with the cake, you might want to use "about", although there could still be reasons to say "with". Neither usage is wrong. You really need a context.

Comment: Thank you very much. As a non-native speaker, it just feels the same to me.

Comment: To me, _do with_ definitely implies handling the cake. "What should I do with it?" "Put it on the table there, please." _Do about_ could refer to arrangements. "Mary's ill - what shall we do about a cake for John's birthday?" "Ask Sally if she can make one."